# LocationService ionic google-maps object failing for ios, but works in android

Tags: android, ios, cordova, ionic-framework, geolocation

I have found on android that using geolocation from Google Maps JavaScript API and from the Ionic Framework has caused issues of being very slow or not working at all. I then found a second geolocation module for Ionic called LocationService, from this documentation: https://github.com/ionic-team/ionic-native-google-maps/blob/master/documents/locationservice/README.md. The issue that I am having is although this Location module is working for Android, it is not working on ios or by serving the app on localhost. Below is the error that I am getting and my code that sets the map's center. I am editing this.

map.html:

```
<ion-header>
  <ion-navbar>
    <ion-title>
      Map
    </ion-title>
  </ion-navbar>
</ion-header>
<ion-content>
  <div id='map'></div>
</ion-content>
```

map.ts:

```
import { Component, ViewChild, ElementRef } from '@angular/core';
import { NavController, Platform, Navbar } from 'ionic-angular';
import { Geolocation } from '@ionic-native/geolocation';
import {
  LocationService,
  GoogleMap,
  GoogleMapOptions,
  MyLocation,
  GoogleMaps
} from '@ionic-native/google-maps';

declare var google: any;
@Component({
  selector: 'page-map',
  templateUrl: 'map.html',
})
export class OfficeLocatorPage {
  @ViewChild(Navbar) navBar: Navbar;
  map: any;
  mapOptions:any;
  trafficEnabled = false;
  transitEnabled = false;
  bicycleEnabled = false;
  markers = [];
  places = [];
  trafficLayer = new google.maps.TrafficLayer();
  transitLayer = new google.maps.TransitLayer();
  bicycleLayer = new google.maps.BicyclingLayer();
  myLocation: any;
  infoWindow: any;
  isInfoWindowShown: boolean = false;

  constructor(private navCtrl: NavController, private platform: Platform, private geolocation: Geolocation) {
  }

  ionViewDidLoad() {
    this.navBar.backButtonClick = (e:UIEvent)=>{
      this.navCtrl.pop({animate: true, animation: "transition", direction: "left", duration: 300});
    };
 }
  ionViewDidEnter() {
      this.platform.ready().then(() => {
        this.places = [];
        this.initMap(this);
    });
  }
  initMap(scopeObj) {
    LocationService.getMyLocation({enableHighAccuracy: true}).then((location: MyLocation) => {
      this.setLocation(location.latLng);
    }).catch((error: any) => {
      // Can not get location, permission refused, and so on...
      console.log(error);
    });
  }

  setLocation(location) {
      this.map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
          center: location,
          zoom: 10,
          disableDefaultUI: true
      });
      let image = {
        url: "assets/icon/blue_dot.png", // url
        scaledSize: new google.maps.Size(25, 33), // scaled size
        origin: new google.maps.Point(0,0), // origin
        anchor: new google.maps.Point(0, 0) // ancho
      };
      let marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: location,
        map: this.map,
        icon: image
      });
      this.myLocation = new google.maps.LatLng(location.lat, location.lng);
    }
```

Error log:

```
Error: Uncaught (in promise): TypeError: Cannot read property 'LocationService' of null
TypeError: Cannot read property 'LocationService' of null
    at http://localhost:8100/build/vendor.js:78338:35
    at new t (http://localhost:8100/build/polyfills.js:3:21506)
    at Function.LocationService.getMyLocation
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error seems to only show when serving the app in a web browser, Xcode just needed to be cleaned and rebuilt, so the map shows up and works now. I don't believe that it will work on the browser when running the command "ionic serve", because LocationService is an ionic native module and can't be used unless the app is installed on Android or iOS.